# General way to calculate the amount of different d6 results?

Tags: combinations

I need a way to control that my program finds the right amount of different results you can get on nd6. Let's say that i have 2d6, then the total amount of results would be $6^2 = 36$. But the different amount of results would be 21, i know this since i counted. The thing is that i do not want to count for 10d6.

Comment: So you want to regard the dice as indistinguishable? A throw of 5-3 is the same regardless of which die had the 5 and which the 3?

Comment: Yes, order doesnt matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be translated into a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem, where you are putting some number of balls (throws) into one of six boxes (results). For the 2d6 case that you worked out, the answer is as you found, $\binom{2+6-1}{2}= 21$. So the number of different outcomes for 10d6 is just $\binom{10+6-1}{10} = 3003$